# VBA macro to loop through filter, Copy reference cell, and then paste in separate sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with source data in columns `Sheet1!A6:R553`.

In `Sheet1!A3:R3`, I have formulas that pull specific information out of my data table in `Sheet1!A6:R553` that I want copied to a different sheet.

Column A acts as my project name column, while column B holds order numbers. In my case, there are multiple order numbers per project.

I am looking for a script to filter and loop through all the unique order numbers in Column B one by one, then copy cells `A3:R3` to `Sheet2!A12:R12` for as many rows as there are unique order numbers.

Example: Assume there are 5 projects in my data sheet. I will filter the data using another macro to select Project_1. I would then like a command button to active a macro that will filter to the first order number in Column B, copy `Sheet1!A3:R3` to `Sheet2!A12:R12`, then filter to the second order number in Project_1, and repeat the process. This should go on until all unique order numbers have been filtered and looped through.

Thank you for any help you're able to provide.

Comment: http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=122:excel-vba-loops-with-examples-for-loop-do-while-loop-do-until-loop&catid=79&Itemid=475

Comment: Edit: Didn't to post, sorry. @Tim, thanks for your help, but I'm a newbie when it comes to coding at the moment.